# How to get file list from site resources url in java

Tags: java, url, static, resources

I want to get the static file list of another site.

Example:

```
 https://static.naver.com/images/pencil.png
 https://static.naver.com/images/note.png
 https://static.naver.com/images/table.png
```

How do I get the image list from 'https://static.naver.com/images/' in java?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to get file list from website?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like that:

```
File folder = new File("your/path");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
      if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
      } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. However, this is possible when looking for a file on your PC path, but not when looking for a file list in the URL resources path.